# Why does Stormbreaker's handle stay?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

At the end of *Avengers: Infinity War*, we have seen Groot been erased due to Thanos' snap.

So shouldn't the handle he made for Stormbreaker get erased as well?

Just wanted to know if there is any story plot behind the snap I am missing.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanos' "snap" erased half of all **LIFE** in the universe.

Since Groot was alive he was one of those erased as part of the snap.

BUT, the handle of Stormbreaker is made from the "dead" (sacrificed) arm of Groot ...so it's not alive and so not affected by the Infinity Snap.

Comment: +1, Nice answer, but that opens a lot of questions about other non-alive remains left behind by the erased ones, like hair or clothes. Also, about what happens to other life forms living inside the "erased one" (like your intestinal flora)

Comment: I am now imaging news reports of very small sinkholes opening up in half the world's graves.

Comment: @xDaizu It does leave some questions, but I think the key is related to how physically attached those things were to them. Even clothes are fairly attached to the wearer, as if the wearer walks away, the clothes go with. Tony stark holding Peter does not go with him should he have gotten up and walked away (ignoring the situation), but the spidey suit would have without some action to take it off.

Comment: Further questions arise from the fact that Groot has already been shown completely regenerating from small fragments of himself.  Presumably the same thing could at least be attempted using the handle, or a portion of it.

Answer (score 6):

The snap does not remove a life's history from the universe, merely stops them from existing going forward.

Groot Jr's arm is no longer part of him. He cannot make it grow, sprout flowers, change it's form etc. It cannot say, "I am Groot". So when Groot Jr. is turned to ash, there is no reason for something no longer part of him to be effected.

Comment: 'It cannot say, "I am Groot"' - Unless you put it in some dirt and wait awhile.

Comment: @aroth, not every piece of father Groot can become a baby. Otherwise Xandar would be over run.

Comment: Not necessarily.  It seems to take a fair bit of time and care under the proper conditions to get a completely new Groot from a Groot fragment.  Perhaps without _exactly_ the right environment pieces of Groot just lie dormant.

Answer (score 1):

The MCU writers made it pretty clear that only things that were on a person's body at the time they turned to ash were destroyed. For example, in the post-credits, Maria Hill gets turned completely to ash, including her clothing and whatever may have been in her pockets, but Nick Fury is able to grab a pager, call out an emergency code, and then dropped the pager before the ash reached it, and it survives the snap, even though nothing else of Nick's personal effects survived.

A helicopter crashed into a building, and a car crashed in front of Nick and Maria, demonstrating that it doesn't affect things that the person was touching, just things that could be considered "on their person" at the time of death. Since the handle is nowhere near Groot Jr, it's not "on his person" and wasn't affected. Also, it is hinted that a cutting of Groot is not the same as the original, much like you are a separate person than your mother or father. Even if you submit that Stormbreaker's handle was alive, there's no evidence that it is the same living creature that is Groot Jr.

Either way, the handle had an equal 50% chance of surviving even if it was alive, and that 50% chance would have been independent of Groot Jr's own chance of survival. Odds are, if it were alive, this information was withheld by the writers as a way to possibly revive Groot again in the next movie, even if the heroes never figure out how to recover from the snap.